# Azure Automation error

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-automation

I have the following PowerShell script in Azure Automation. All it does is running a stored procedure called `AddWeeks`.

```
workflow GenerateWeeks
{
    $serverInstance="[my_db_server]" 
    $userName="[my_username]"
    $password="[my_password]"

    [void][System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName('Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo') |out-null
    $ServerConnection =new-object Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common.ServerConnection $serverInstance,$userName, $password
    $ServerConnection.ExecuteNonQuery("declare @date date set @date=getdate()   exec [xxxx].dbo.AddWeeks 300,@date")
```

}

But when I do a test run, I get the following error:

```
Runbook definition is invalid. Could not find type Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common.ServerConnection. Load the type(s) and try again.
```

what is the problem?

***edit***

With the help of jisaak, I have this final working version:

```
workflow GenerateWeeks
{
    InlineScript 
    {
        $con = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
        $con.ConnectionString = "Server = xxx; Database=xxx; User ID = xxx; Password = xxx;"
        $con.Open();
        $sql = "declare @date date set @date=getdate()   exec [xxx].dbo.AddWeeks 300,@date"
        $cmd = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand($sql,$con)
        $cmd.CommandTimeout=300
        $cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()  
    }
}
```

I set the CommandTimeout since when I debug it throws an exception saying:

```
A transport-level error has occurred when receiving results from the server. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 0 - The specified network name is no longer available.)
```

Answer (score 1):

The error points it out, `Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common.ServerConnection` is not available. Use  [System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection(v=vs.110).aspx) instead:

```
$con = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
$con.ConnectionString = "Server = $serverInstance; User ID = $userName; Password = $password;"
$con.Open();
$cmd = $con.CreateCommand("declare @date date set @date=getdate()   exec [xxxx].dbo.AddWeeks 300,@date")
$cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

Im not sure, but you maybe have to wrap the script in a inlinescript.

Comment: Thank you so much! I made some changes on your code and posted the working version above. I am curious - `[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName` doesn't work on Azure? but it works on local environment.